# Simple routing on the page. How do I set up the correct display?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There are links on the page and each link has it's own output i.e

> this page is 1 for `id = 1`, this page is 2 for `id = 2` and so on.

But the fact is that everything is displayed at once, I want to render as per the link click.

How can I fix my code so that everything works correctly?

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-buck-94x6y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are rendering multiple `Switch` components when you render the routes by iterating over `this.state.cards`. The solution is just to move the `Switch` component outside from the return value in `this.state.cards.map(() => {...})`.

You don't need to loop over the `card` array to create the `Route` components if you want them to match by the pathname of `api/events/:id`. If for some reason you want only three `Route` components with paths `/api/events/1`, `/api/events/2` and `api/events/3` you don't even need to match them by `api/events/:id` you can just loop over the card array and return a `Route` component with `path={"/api/events/"+id}`

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Main from "./Main";
import Description from "./Description";
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      card: [1, 2, 3]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              {this.state.card.map(id => {
                return (
                  <Link to={"/api/events/" + id}>
                    <Main number={id} />
                  </Link>
                );
              })}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/api/events/:id" component={Description} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You don't need to pass the `id` as prop to the `Description` component if you choose to render the routes matched by pathname `/api/events/:id`. You can  make use of `match.params` to get the id. See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cloud-b20dr?file=/src/App.js) for demo.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need. But what if I want to transfer some data to the Description component as well? For example, a name or any other text. (for example, the data comes from the server)

Comment: For example, I have an array of 'names' and I want to use 'map' like you did for 'Main'. Then I have all the names displayed at once.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. Instead of prop drilling from `Main` to the child component then to another child component, you can either use global state for server data or have component level state using custom hooks. I will update the codesandbox where the `Description` component makes use of the `id` to get remote data from the server.

Comment: Look, please, I updated the code for better understanding. I get the array I wrote in state, so I can get user_id in the 'Main' component, but I can't get user_name in the 'Description' component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-violet-6fy0j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, I get it. But let me ask you something, do you only have a limited number of cards or you have like thousands of cards that you fetch from backend? It is not a good idea to map over all the cards and render 1000 route components so you can just pass props to the route children. Here is a solution using `location` state instead but i can not guarantee this is the best solution for your use-case. If this works for you, let me know. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cloud-b20dr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Everything works as it should, but if I refresh the page, an error appears.
Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: That is why I said that it would not be a good solution, because the state that is passed is temporary. You have to let me know if you are going to have a finite number of cards to make routes or you are fetching the data from a backend? So that I can update the answer properly.

Comment: I get the data from the backend, data can change. But the data array isn't very large.

Comment: Great, so can you not fetch the data in the `Description` component by using the value of `match.params.id`? Why fetch all the data at once in one component ? Is the API not compatible? I will be updating the sandbox where data is fetched from server.

Comment: I tried to get data this way {this.props.names[params.id - 1]}. but it didn't work out. Obtaining data in this way may not be the best solution, but we have this application architecture. I didn't work with the backend, I just get the data from there, that's all.

Comment: Here is an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cloud-b20dr?file=/src/App.js) using a fake json API, with dynamic routes and the `Description` component fetches the data by the `match.params.id`. Have a look and let me know it something like that can work for your use-case.

Comment: Excuse me, can you help me one last time? Your array is called 'data', but the array I get isn't called anything. How do I get the data out of there? I updated the code and added an API link to it. This works for /2, /5 and /8.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-forest-v4fs3?file=/src/Description.js

Comment: Sure, here you go, updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-solomon-ixjqv?file=/src/Description.js)

Comment: Sorry, I copied your code and pasted it into the project, but the 'id' and 'user' in the 'Description' component are 'undefined' and 'null' after each click. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also modified `App.js` in the sandbox, have a look at all the files in the sandbox. See if you are using something different in your code.

Comment: I found a mistake. Thank you very much for your help! You solved my problem.

Comment: When exact is true for a route, it will only match if the `path` matches the `location.pathname` exactly. See the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the list of `IDs` as a static route generator. You can do it with a loop of `Link` and `Route`. 
I made a CodeSandbox for better understanding

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-surf-48nhp?file=/src/App.js